How do the $j$-invariants give us a dominant morphism?
Let $S$ be the surface defined by $x^a+y^a+z^b = 1$, for $b \geq 2$. The following excerpt is taken from An $abcd$ theorem over function fields and applications by Corvaja and Zannier.

[Suppose] we had infinitely many pairs $(E, \phi)$ for an elliptic curve $E$ and a rational map $\phi:E \to S$ of bounded degree, with a Zariski dense union of images. By looking at the $j$-invariants we would obtain a dominant morphism $\pi: \mathcal{E} \to S$ from an affine elliptic surface $\mathcal{E}$ to $S$.

I do not understand the last line, how is $\mathcal{E}$ related to the $j$-invariants of the infinitely many elliptic curves?
